# Regex - digits after string not greedy

Tags: regex

Data to work with is `...deliveryProfilID: 22261,offerID: '83627489',productKindID: '2',...`

It's irregular string from which I have to pull digits of `offerID`

So I need regex to return `83627489`

I got [working one](http://regex101.com/r/dD1iE9/1) but it's awful: `offerID\s{0,}:\s{0,}'(\d*)'\s{0,}`

I want to use [something like this](http://regex101.com/r/dD1iE9/2): `offerID.*(\d*)` but it selects to much.

Comment: Replacing `{0,}` by `*` makes it already less awful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
offerID[\s]*:[\s]*'(\d*)'
```

is probably more readable?

but as sp00m said...

```
offerID\s*:\s*'(\d)'
```

is already better.

and  Avinash Raj's suggestion of

```
offerID[\D]*(\d*)'
```

might be my favorite but the brackets aren't necessary.

```
offerID\D*(\d*)'
```

Works too.

Answer (score 1):

A little modification would work:

```
offerID\D*(\d*)
```

Unlike `.*`, `\D*` only matches non-digits. And of course you can further improve it if needed:

```
offerID:\D*'(\d*)'
```

Comment: More simpler, `[^\d]*` would be written as `\D*`

Comment: Is what I need but better: `offerID[\D]*(\d*)`

Comment: What's the need for character class ? @Ultra